# Getting same values while editing 2nd value

Tags: html, angularjs

**HTML**

```
<div class="trow-collapse">
    <form role="form" name="Notes" id="Notes">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <p>{{partner.address}}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="partner-note">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Note</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <textarea rows="7" class="form-control" name="note{{$index}}">{{partner.note}}</textarea>
                            <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="saveNote(partner.id)">Save</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$scope.saveNote = function(id){
    console.log(id);       

    var formDataObj = {};
    var myForm = document.getElementById("Notes");
    //console.log(myForm);
    formDataObj.note = myForm.note.value;  

    console.log(formDataObj.note) ;

    getPartners.note(id,formDataObj).then(function(response)
    {       
        $scope.partners = response.data;   
        //$state.go('partners', {}, { reload: true });   
    }); 
};
```

I am getting the first note value while i edit the second one in console log but getting different id.m using ng-repeat.plz help me to sort this out.i want to save data in database.

Comment: use ng-model and set to parent.note in textarea and on click pass the parent object and get the value from the parent obj.

Comment: can u explain by giving an example...m new to it!!

Comment: i hv used note{{$index}}...can u u plz tell me hw can nw i get the value in my controller?

Answer (score 0):

use ng-model in textarea, using that you can get the textarea value. And pass the partner obj on ng-click

```
<div class="trow-collapse">
        <form role="form" name="Notes" id="Notes">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <p>{{partner.address}}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="partner-note">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Note</label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <textarea rows="7" class="form-control" name="note" ng-model="partner.note"></textarea>
                                <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="saveNote(partner)">Save</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

In your controller use the parent.note to get the value of note

```
$scope.saveNote = function(partner){
    console.log(partner);       

};
```

Comment: any idea using $index?

Comment: it's not wrking

Comment: I have changed your code and posted above please check the ng-model in textarea and ng-click in button next to text area. and I cant find where you used ng-repeat, so I added myself in fiddle but not in the code posted above.